# Nifi using python web scraper

Tags: python, apache-nifi

i have been struggling with an issue for days.
My situation is this: i want to get into hadoop and realtime analytics. As ax example, i want to scrape some prices from a particular website. The script works on my laptop but when i move it to NIFI it starts giving issue. I have a Raspbarian Desktop virtual environment setup on my laptop. I am using NIFI to get data from an ExecuteScript. I have this code which works on my native laptop:

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import HTML

page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ1.htm')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

As soon as i put it into NIFI, it start complaining about "no module named HTML in  line 2. I know this is a module issue but i just don't have the necessary experience to identify the root cause and fix the issue.

Things to note:

1. I switched form python 2.7 to python 3.5 by using the alternative method.
2. in the Execute Script component, i set the module directory to the following:
   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages,/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Is there anyone which is familiar with this environment to assist me with the missing modules and how to fix this ?

Comment: ExecuteScript processor uses [jython](http://www.jython.org/) to run python code. if you have python installed, you can use [ExecuteProcess](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) or [ExecuteStreamCommend](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processors to run pure python.

Comment: Hello, I switched to ExecuteStreamCommand now and the syntax seems to be working. Atlough now i cannot utilize the NIFI libraries to handle Flowfiles. Do you have an example an executeStreamCommand?

Comment: When you use ExecuteStreamCommand the stdin represents in flow file and stdout represents output file.  And no extra libraries required

Comment: Thanks for the infromation, i will test that out. is that the correct way of doing things? i was looking at ExecuteProcess but i cannot find how to import the modules org.apache.nifi.processor.io into python. it's frustrating when you are a beginner in this area.

Comment: With ExecuteProcess or ExecuteStreamCommand, you won't need any NiFi processor modules, they handle all that for you, and just let you access the flow file content as stdin and write to the outgoing flow file via stdout (as daggett said)

Comment: Any reason you're not just using the built in GetHTTP processor?